# gRPC, TensorFlow Serving "Received RST_STREAM with error code 2"

Tags: python, tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to call my TF Artificial Neural Network Model, deployed in Cloud Foundry environment of the SAP Cloud and transformed from Keras Model to TensorFlow SavedModel format.

Therefore I have an Python2 API using TensorFlow Serving and gRPC. I'm already getting errors when trying to execute the API in a local venv.

API code:

```
import os
import grpc
from grpc.beta import implementations
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2

MODEL_NAME = str(os.getenv('MODEL_NAME', ''))
MODEL_SERVER_HOST = str(os.getenv('MODEL_SERVER_HOST', ''))
MODEL_SERVER_PORT = int(os.getenv('MODEL_SERVER_PORT', ''))
ROOT_CERT = str(os.getenv('ROOT_CERT', '')).replace('\\n', '\n')

def metadata_transformer(metadata):
    additions = []

    token = 'Bearer <my Access Token>'
    additions.append(('authorization', token))
    return tuple(metadata) + tuple(additions)

credentials = implementations.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=ROOT_CERT)
channel = implementations.secure_channel(MODEL_SERVER_HOST,MODEL_SERVER_PORT, credentials)
stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel, metadata_transformer=metadata_transformer)

#grpc non beta --> does not work for tf serving? -->Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, Name resolution failure
#credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=ROOT_CERT)
#server = "'" + MODEL_SERVER_HOST + ':' + str(MODEL_SERVER_PORT) + "'"
#channel = grpc.secure_channel(server, credentials)
#non beta --> can't add metadata --> adding in request below
#stub = prediction_service_pb2.PredictionServiceStub(channel)

# test:
import numpy as np
data = np.matrix([<a Test matrix>])

request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
request.model_spec.name = MODEL_NAME
#request.model_spec.signature_name = 'ticketCatFeature2'
request.inputs['input'].CopyFrom(
    tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(data, shape=[200], dtype=tf.float32))

#out = stub.Predict(request, 200, metadata=metadata_transformer)
out = stub.Predict(request, 200)
```

The following error message is appearing:

> grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INTERNAL, details="Received RST_STREAM with error code 2")

As you can see I've also tried to do the request with the non beta features of TF Serving and gRPC (the commented sections). But this leads to another error:

> grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, Name resolution failure)>

Total gRPC debugs: https://files.fm/u/d8htpjyq

I have no clue how to solve this problem and can't see a workarround to call my AI model with another framework, as SAP Cloud only supports TF models with TF 1.4. I would appreciate some help with the gRPC errors.

**Status Update:** I Also tested to load and run my model in a jupyter notebook with the same example data and it works as expected, my AI model should not be the cause of the error

Comment: I'm also facing same issue :( Were you able to solve it?